# Laravel - Keep session data upon return from Socialite but not yet submitted form

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I'm trying to pass data from a form to a controller, but that hasn't yet been submitted.

**Is there any way to pass all of the input data to the controller but still using a Get route?**

Here's my code so far:

**web.php**

```
Route::any('login/{service}', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider')->name('social');
Route::get('login/{service}/callback', 'Auth\LoginController@handleProviderCallback');
```

**LoginController.php**

```
public function redirectToProvider(Request $request, $service)
{
    echo "<pre>\n";var_dump(
        $request->session()->all()
    );die;

}
```

Just to note: I am trying to dump the information that I have from the Request. Here, I can see that I have none of the information from the inputs.

Here is the data that I get:

```
array(4) {
  ["_token"]=>
  string(40) "UoYyc1IBZ0ibSC3Kd234as39ui1JvW7U6sI5qBMVV"
  ["_previous"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["url"]=>
    string(45) "https://mywebsite.com/"
  }
  ["_flash"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["old"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
    ["new"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
  ["state"]=>
  string(40) "4cFV2oh3e7VZw7H9asd2343q8G5IQsq1k3ulsKG0"
}
```

Comment: you can create a public variable then save the value in it and access it in the other function

Comment: You can make an ajax call to pass data from a form to a controller that hasn't yet been submitted. However I'm not sure why this is required.